# Layout xml to Java code

Tags: android, android-layout

Does anybody know some tool which convert layout.xml into Java Code generated programmatically. Simple example:

```
   <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/redownload_of_assets"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/btn_redownload_of_assets" />



Button button = New Button(this)
button.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Reason of that solution is that I need add some controls into FrameLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fr_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/slider_menu"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Perhaps you should think about using xml instead? Or you could provide information about WHY do you need such a tool. There could be a better solution then :)

Comment: Okay. But do you really need to add the controls dinamically from code? Otherwise You could just put them into the FrameLayout inside the xml. IF you need to add them dinamically (because you want to add an unknown number of buttons) you could use a ListView or something else...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this service http://www.xmltojava.com/ it does not support custom view's but still can be useful. Any way i strongly recommend use plain xml. If you need to change layout dynamically there is two options.

1. Use [ViewStub](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewStub.html)
2. Add all view's you need to layout and hide/show it when you need.

Answer (score 0):

All xml tags are actually classes which you just inflate. Just give the layout and id, access it via the java and add whatever methods you want.